# How to install SQL Server PowerShell module on my company's server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Environment:

- Windows 2016 Server Standard
- PowerShell 5
- Has Internet connection
- Running PowerShell as administrator
- JFrog is something new we're implementing but not sure if fully on server or not. I know very little about it.

When I try to run the following:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

I get following prompt:

> PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories

I answer yes to the prompt and get the following error:

> WARNING: Unable to download from URI
> 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check
> your internet connection. PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider :
> No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider
> 'NuGet'. The package  provider requires 'PackageManagement' and
> 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
>
> WARNING: Unable to download from URI
> 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check
> your internet connection. PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider :
> Unable to find package provider 'NuGet'. It may not be imported yet.
> Try 'Get-PackageProvider
> -ListAvailable'.

What is going on?

I tried:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 
Get-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Force
```

I got the following:

> Get-PackageProvider -Name nuget -Force WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload
> «go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «» WARNING:
> Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your
> internet connection. WARNING: Unable to download from URI
> 'go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
> Get-PackageProvider : Unable to find package provider 'nuget'. It may
> not be imported yet. Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

**Update**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

> WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload
> «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check
> your internet connection. WARNING: Unable to download from URI
> 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
> Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search
> criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires
> 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified
> package has the tags. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider)
>   ```
>
> [Install-PackageProvider], Excepti     on
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
>
> PS C:\Windows\sy

**Update 2:**

[image]

**Update 3:**

[image]

Comment: You might be running into a TLS version mismatch. IMO, MS really botched this. But you can try `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` in your session and attempt the download again. If it works, just jam that in your powershell profile and every session going forward will be g2g.

Comment: I updated the OP with results (Update 2)

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/when-powershellget-v1-fails-to-install-the-nuget-provider/)?

Comment: Do you access the internet over a company proxy? If so, add the `-Proxy` parameter to the `Install-Module` cmdlet (and if needed also the `-ProxyCredential` parameter).