# PowerShell 5.1 and sqlcmd.exe - Is there a way to pass arguments to a string query?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

Environment:
Windows Server 2016 Standard
Windows 10 Pro
PowerShell 5.1

Is there a way to pass arguments to a string query (instead of an -i input.sql)? I don't have Invoke-Sqlcmd available to me either. The following does not recognize arg1 in the print statement.

```
$test = sqlcmd -v arg1='hello_world' -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; 
print $(arg1)" -W -h -1 -d database1 -S "(localdb)\ProjectsV13" 
Write-Output $test
```

Comment: I wish https://stackoverflow.com/q/71623996/139698

Comment: Instead of calling sqlcmd, use the .Net [SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) library instead. Object-oriented approach, no building command strings, strong typing... What's not to like?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$x="hello"
$sql = "print '$x'"
Write-Output $sql
$test = sqlcmd -E -Q $sql -W -h -1 -d database1 -S "(localdb)\ProjectsV13" 
Write-Output $test
```